# Firebase offline persistence: Does it disable online connectivity?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

See here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities

I use Firebase Realtime Database to connect a Google Cloud backend with an Android app written in Kotlin. I use offline persistence. I noticed something strange: Say I have 2 endpoints, ep1 and ep2. Then say I issue these commands in the Android app:

```
Firebase.database.setPersistenceEnabled(true)
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("ep1").keepSynced(true)
```

Then what I observe is that changes to ep2 are not seen by the Android app.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: "Then what I observe is that changes to ep2 are not seen by the Android app." Can you clarify what you mean here? Or better yet: show in code what the problem is?

Comment: Withdrawing this, apologies. Digging deeper into the code I realized it was caching the cache in its own data structure...

Answer (score 1):

[FirebaseDatabase#setPersistenceEnabled(boolean isEnabled)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase#setPersistenceEnabled(boolean)) method:

> The Firebase Database client will cache synchronized data and keep track of all writes you've initiated while your application is running.

This means that all the writes that you're performing while you're offline, are added to a queue in the local cache. As soon as you regain connectivity, all operations are synchronized with the Firebase servers.

On the other hand, when you're using the following line of code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("ep1").keepSynced(true)
```

[Query#keepSynced(boolean keepSynced)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#keepSynced(boolean)) method:

> By calling `keepSynced(true)` on a location, the data for that location will automatically be downloaded and kept in sync, even when no listeners are attached to that location.

As the name says, this method keeps your above reference synchronized in the local cache. What it actually does, it literally just attaches an empty listener to the `ep1` reference.

> Then what I observe is that changes to ep2 are not seen by the Android app.

If there is no listener attached to the `ep2` reference, or you don't call `.keepSynced(true)`, you cannot read the data at the location. That's why you cannot see it. So you either attach a listener yourself, in your application code or call `.keepSynced(true)` as you do in the case of `ep1`.

But remember, calling `.keepSynced(true)` has nothing to do with the offline persistence mechanism. When you call `setPersistenceEnabled()` it means that you enable/disable the option to have a local cache while calling `.keepSynced(true)`, it basically attaches a listener to the reference/query it points to.

Comment: Hey Yanay. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Thank you Alex. As noted above, RTDB data was cached by the app in its own data structure and that's what was put on the screen. Nothing to do with Firebase, my bad.